# Proof of separable Hilbert space has an orthonormal countable basis

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I read a proof about the  separable Hilbert space has an orthonormal countable basis. The following is the proof.

---

assuming $\{x_n\}_1^\infty$ is the countable dense subset of $X$, then $\{x_n\}_1^\infty$ has  a linearly independent subset $\{y_n\}_1^N, (N<\infty  \text{ or } N=\infty)$ such that
$$
span\{y_n\}_1^N=span\{x_n\}_1^\infty   \tag{2}
$$
Do the Gram-Schmidy process for $\{y_n\}_1^N$, then we have orthonormal countable set $\{e_n\}_1^N$. Since
$$
\overline{span\{e_n\}_1^N}=\overline{span\{y_n\}_1^N}=\overline{span\{x_n\}_1^\infty}=X   \tag{1}
$$
Therefore,  $\{e_n\}_1^N$ is orthonormal countable basis of $X$.

---

But in my view,  $\{e_n\}_1^N$ is orthonormal countable basis of $span\{x_n\}_1^\infty$ by (2), why the (1) means that  $\{e_n\}_1^N$ is orthonormal countable basis of $X$ ?

I guess that if $\{e_n\}$ is basis of $X$, then, $\{e_n\}$ is basis of $\overline X$. But I don't know how to prove it.

Definition of basis in Hilbert space : $X$ is a inner space, $\{x_\alpha: \alpha\in \Lambda\}$ is basis of $X$,  if $\forall x\in X$, $x$ can be presented as
$$
x=\sum\limits_{\alpha\in\Lambda} (x,e_\alpha)x_\alpha
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An orthonormal set in  a subspace is also orthonomal in the whole space. For showing that p$$
x=\sum\limits_{\alpha\in\Lambda} (x,e_\alpha)x_\alpha
$$ it is enough to show that $\langle x-\sum\limits_{\alpha\in\Lambda} (x,e_\alpha)x_\alpha, y\rangle=0$ for all $y \in X$. By continuity of inner product it is enough to prove this when $y \in span \{x_n\}$ which you already know.